# CMUSphinx - Using CMUSphinx for Speech to Text without grammar (gram) file

Tags: java, speech-to-text, cmusphinx

I am very new to Sphinx. I want to use Sphinx for speech to text conversion. I tried to google it. Sphinx uses gram file to match the word. But this way its limiting the possiblity of words. I want to work with or just convert every word being spoken to text. How to do that? If you can post example then it would be great. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large vocabulary recognition you can use generic US English language model

https://sourceforge.net/projects/cmusphinx/files/Acoustic%20and%20Language%20Models/US%20English%20Generic%20Language%20Model/

To learn more about CMUSphinx read the tutorial

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorial